# `*': negative argument (ArgumentError) Ruby

Tags: ruby

I keep getting this negative argument error when running this code in the Codewars IDE. It  runs fine in terminal but in Codewars it both passes the test and runs this error message simultaneously.

```
STDERR
main.rb:5:in `*': negative argument (ArgumentError)
    from main.rb:5:in `maskify'
    from main.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

The code is

```
def maskify(cc)
  x = cc.to_s
  y = "#" * (x.length - 4)
  return y + x.slice(-4..-1)
end
```

I'm new to Ruby but I've not heard anywhere that it has a problem with negative numbers being used in .slice. Am I missing something here? Thanks.

Comment: It's not `slice`. It's [String#*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-2A). Evidentially, `cc.to_s.length < 4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not considering cases when `cc` is shorter than 4 symbols.

And expression `"#" * (x.length - 4)` raises the error because you can't multiply a string by a negative number.

Try to use `Array#max` method to handle this:

```rb
"#" * [x.length - 4, 0].max
```